# Lag a column using linux

Tags: linux, lag

How can I lag a column using linux? For example in SAS the below code would work.

```
lag2=lag(error2);
lag3=lag2(error2);
lag4=lag3(error2);
lag5=lag4(error2);
```

The input is the following

```
id1 id2 id3 numb error 
1 2 1 1_135098 OK  
0 2 0 1_267940 code3
0 0 0 1_305793 OK 
0 2 0 1_393248 code3 
0 5 1 1_434180 OK 
0 2 0 1_471078 code3
```

The output I would like is, where I am lagging the fifth column 4 times

```
id1 id2 id3 numb error lag2 lag3 lag4 lag5
1 2 1 1_135098 OK . . . . 
0 2 0 1_267940 code3 OK . . .
0 0 0 1_305793 OK code3 ok . .
0 2 0 1_393248 code3 ok code3 ok .
0 5 1 1_434180 OK code3 ok code3 ok
0 2 0 1_471078 code3 ok code3 ok code3
```

Answer (score 0):

Created below 2 files with mentioned content

01HW497089:tmp Controller$ cat l.txt 
.. 
ok       ..
code3    ok    ..
ok       code3  ok    ..
code3    ok   code3   ok 
ok      code3  ok      code3

01HW497089:tmp Controller$ cat h.txt
1 2 1 1_135098 OK
0 2 0 1_267940 code3
0 0 0 1_305793 OK 
0 2 0 1_393248 code3 
0 5 1 1_434180 OK 
0 2 0 1_471078 code3

Output

Command paste h.txt l.txt

01HW497089:tmp Controller$ paste h.txt  l.txt 
1 2 1 1_135098 OK   .. 
0 2 0 1_267940 code3    ok    ..
0 0 0 1_305793 OK   code3 ok   ..
0 2 0 1_393248 code3    ok    code3 ok   ..
0 5 1 1_434180 OK   code3  ok   code3  ok 
0 2 0 1_471078 code3    ok    code3  ok    code3
ls- ltr 
01HW497089:tmp Controller$

Answer (score 0):

Below one is script and input file

As I checked it worked fine

h.txt
1 2 1 1_135098 OK
0 2 0 1_267940 code3
0 0 0 1_305793 OK
0 2 0 1_393248 code3
0 5 1 1_434180 OK
0 2 0 1_471078 code3

## !/bin/bash

for z in 1 2 3 4 5 6
do
for j in ".. " "ok    .." "code3 ok   .." "ok    code3 ok   .." "code3  ok   code3  ok " "ok    code3  ok    code3"
do
echo $j
sed  ""$z"s/.*/&'$j'/g" h.txt
done
done

Comment: Sorry I didnt get a notification. Would this script work on a file of a million lines though?